# duplicate table row with drop down list control in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to duplicate a table row on button click, specifically, a row with controls in (drop down list etc). The user will be inputting data and then sending it to a database when all rows are complete. The purpose is to reduce user time as many fields will be the same on each row possibly.

I have this code attempting to duplicate row controls, it doesnt copy but rather 'move' the control. Also, why doesn't multiple button clicks result in multiple rows..after one click it wont add any more than one additional. Thanks. **EDIT: yes, is asp:table.**

Current code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
    Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);

    foreach (TableCell cell in Table1.Rows[0].Cells)
    {
      TableCell tCell = new TableCell();

      foreach (Control ctrl in cell.Controls)
      {
          tCell.Controls.Add(ctrl);
      }
      //tCell.Text = cell.Text;
      tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
}
```

Comment: Does this code add new row for you? talking about multiple clicks hope you haven't written something like this `ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(yourButton, null));`. If you have then it wont't trigger another postback event.

Comment: yes it is an asp:table

Comment: and sorry yes that code does insert new row